# UDP socket connecting to multiple clients in java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, hole-punching

So I have a java udp server that's meant to be able to use a middle man program on a public server to hole punch to it's clients so it can be run from anywhere. The middle man works, the hole punching works, but not together.

Whenever I connect a client to the server, the thread with the connection to the middle man crashes with "connected address and packet address differ".

Without overhauling the middle man's code, I need to keep the one socket and port. How can I get this system to work without throwing the illegal argument error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `connect()`. It isn't usually necessary, and it conflicts with your use-case.

Comment: Yep, that was it, I actually knew not to use connect, but it slipped in from some old code somehow and I didn't see it.